# How do I set indenting options for a language in a VSCode extension?

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a VS Code extension for Dart. The convention for Dart is to indent with 2 spaces (ugh, I hate this too) so I'd like to automatically set it when the user opens a Dart file rather than use their defaults.

There's an `insertSpaces` property in the `FormattingOptions` class but it's not clear how I can set this, nor the best way to do it (it would be nicer to set this at a language level than to keep setting it whenever a document is opened, for example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VS Code now has support for per-language indent settings and you can set defaults in your `package.json`:

```
"configurationDefaults": {
    "[dart]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 2,
        "editor.insertSpaces": true
    },
```

Comment: Where is "package.json"? Can I set this once for all my projects?

Comment: @TedHenry This question/answer relates to doing it at the extension author, not as a user. If you want to set it as an end user, you put it in your usual VS Code settings without the `configurationDefaults` section (see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings).

Comment: Thanks. I manage to configure the number of spaces to 4 for Dart as you suggested. When I use the automatic code formatting command, it is still using 2 spaces. Any way to fix that?

Comment: @TedHenry Unfortunately not - the Dart formatter is not flexible. See https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/914 for details.

Comment: Thanks for the info. 

Comment: Be sure to add a  to that issue if you'd like to see it!

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** see the answer below that applies to newer newer versions of VS Code.

In order to use the `FormattingOptions`, set up a callback for `vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor()` in your extension's `activate()` function:

```
let disposable = vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor((editor) => {
    if(!editor) {
        return;
    }

    if (editor.document.languageId != "your_id_here") {
        return;
    }

    editor.options = {
        cursorStyle: editor.options.cursorStyle,
        insertSpaces: true,
        tabSize: 2
    };
});

context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
```

Comment: I don't seem to have a reference to `editor` in my extensions `activate` function (which makes sense, since it's editor-specific and I need to set for certain files?)

Comment: Sorry about that!  I didn't grab enough of my code earlier!  I've updated the original answer to be a bit more thorough.

Comment: Great; I figured it'd be something like that. Thanks! :)